# Bootstrap compatibility issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with bootstrap and I think I have some compatibility problems.

I use `collapsable navbar` an `hamburger menu` but on `safari` and `ios` browser doesn't seem to work good. It looks like open it twice.

This is my code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="padding-top:20px;">
      <div class="container"  style="width:90%;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"  onclick="hide_menu_button()">
            <img src="img/menuicon.png" id="onClickButton">
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding:0px;"><img id="brandimg" src="img/logo3.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse width" style="text-align:left;font-size:25px;position:absolute; top:-10px; right:0;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbarul">
            <li class="passivx" style="padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:13px; padding-right:50px; text-align:right;"><button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="background-color:#2f2f2f; color:#fff; border:none;font-size:15px;" onclick="show_menu_button()">BEZÁRÁS <b style="font-size:20px;">X</b></button></li>
            <li class="active" id="activelink"><a href="#" style="margin-top:10px">FŐOLDAL<br><img src="img/line.png" style="padding-top:20px;opacity:0.8;width:280px;"></a></li>
            <li class="passiv"><a href="#ref">REFERENCIÁK
              <li class="passiv"><a href="#about" style="padding-top:0px;height:45px;">RÓLUNK<br><img src="img/line.png" style="opacity:0.8; width:280px;padding-top:20px;"></a></li>
              <li class="passiv"><a href="#infokt">INFORMATIKAI OKTATÁS</a></li>
                <li class="passiv"><a href="#infokt2" style="padding-top:0px;height:50px;">SZAKMAI TRÉNINGEK</a></li>
                  <li class="passiv"><a href="#infokt3" style="padding-top:0px;">FELNŐTTKÉPZÉSI SZOLGÁLTATÁSOK<br><img src="img/line.png" style="padding-top:20px;opacity:0.8;width:280px; "></a></li>

                  <li class="passiv" ><a href="#kapcs" style="padding-top:0px;">KAPCSOLAT</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't seem to work good"? Is there a specific error you are getting? Do thinks not look the way you want them too? -- if so what is the problem you have?

Comment: when i open the menu, that is open and for a second it jump right of the site

Comment: Does your full HTML page validate? Does your CSS validate? You've not gotten an answer because you've hardly given us anything to go on. You might want to try setting up a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem.